# Working with sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, search, mysqli

I have the following dilema. I only want one session to be a run at a time, for look at the following query:

```
$get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?(" AND (course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%') OR (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userCategory'] . "%')  ") : '';
```

and

```
//getting the providers
function getProviders(){

            if(isset($_GET['user_query']))
    {
                  $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];
    global $con;
    $get_providers = "select DISTINCT course_provider from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' ) AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";
    $run_providers = mysqli_query($con, $get_providers);

    while ($row_providers=mysqli_fetch_array($run_providers)){
        $provider_title = $row_providers['course_provider'];

        $numberIncrease = 0;

echo '<a href="" id="liSpacing"><label id="labelSearch"><input class="filter" name="provider' . ++$numberIncrease . '" type="checkbox" value="' . $provider_title . '">&nbsp;' . $provider_title . '</label></a> <br />';

}

    }

     else if(isset( $_GET['crs_category']))
    {
                  $search_query2 = $_GET['crs_category'];

    global $con;
    $get_providers = "select DISTINCT course_provider from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query2%' ) AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";
    $run_providers = mysqli_query($con, $get_providers);

    while ($row_providers=mysqli_fetch_array($run_providers)){
        $provider_title = $row_providers['course_provider'];

        $numberIncrease = 0;
}
}
}
```

Below is the page that identifies the session variables:

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_GET['user_query']))

    {
       $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];

 $_SESSION['userSearch'] = $search_query;


  $paginationresults = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses where course_title like '%$search_query%'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY course_date1 ASC");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($paginationresults); //total records
$item_per_page = 10;
//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page); 

}

if(isset($_GET['crs_category']))
    {
       $search_query_category = $_GET['crs_category'];

 $_SESSION['userCategory'] = $search_query_category;


  $paginationresults = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses where course_title like '%$search_query_category%'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY course_date1 ASC");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($paginationresults); //total records
$item_per_page = 10;
//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page); 

}


?>
```

The problem is that I can't have two session running at the same time, as i get an error and need to work out so that it only grabs the session being used. For instance, if the user search for a category it will come out as searchPage.php?crs_category and if they search for a particular item it will come accross as searchPage.php?user_query=html, the problem is that because the previous session is still active it conflicts with the search result.

I hope I was clear, and for any clarification, let me know.

Comment: Not clear at all. A single user only has one session.

Comment: let me clarify, at its current state two session are being called userSearch and userCategory, what I would want is that userCategory session is only started if userSearch session has not been started. and let's say userCategory session start, and then userSearch session was to begin that userCategory would have to be destroy

Comment: Try to define single session as an array with two indexes which are work as an identifier that user is searching for what ? According to that use session

Comment: could you assist me with that, this is the part i am struggling with

Comment: I can give you general idea. Not full code because i don't know what content you are having in your code and how it's working?

Comment: any advice and hint is useful

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the previous session array value when assigning the other session value.

`$_SESSION['userSearch'] = $search_query;`

`unset($_SESSION['userCategory']);`

and

`$_SESSION['userCategory'] = $search_query_category;`

`unset($_SESSION['userSearch']);`

Comment: thank you, but the other issue i have its because of these variables are defined in the query, it gives me the following error when one cannot be found Notice: Undefined index: userCategory in line $get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?(" AND (course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%') OR (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userCategory'] . "%')  ") : '';

Comment: it must for instance ignore the variable that its not been used, because right now its look for example usercategory but that has been unset which make sense since i am looking for usersearch but theres something wrong in my query setup